# Slight problem with day of the week calculation (base doomsday for a century)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, calendar

From this online calculator: http://homer.freeshell.org/dd.cgi using its data I've successfully written a working version, however its data is limited to years 1500 to 2600. I want to modify (and make a better one) so that I can calculate for any year > 2600.

Referring to Table X, is there actually a formula to calculate the [base doomsday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule) for all base centuries (above 2600)?

I've tried working it out myself by putting centuries higher than this e.g. 2700 gave me a base doomsday of '00', 2800 gave '02;, 2900 back to '00' again...

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any other calculators out there that do this?

Two common methods for calculating the day of the week
given a date are Doomsday, which you are using, 
and [Zeller's Congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence)

[www.merlyn.demon.co.uk](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/datelinx.htm) provides
some really interesting information on date/time calculations, various calendar
systems and significant dates as they relate to calendar/date calculations.

Comment: Thanks, Zeller's congruence is a much simpler way!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, that page's “Base Doomsday” is just an offset to allow for the [four-hundred-year cycle of leap day calculations](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Leap_year). So, you can extend it indefinitely into the future simply by adding blocks of four centuries.

Comment: So if I add the next 4 centuries... they would have 3, 2, 0, 5 respectively?

Comment: @Nick are there any other calculators out there that do this? Mine could be wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule#Finding_a_century.27s_anchor_day I'll be seeing if this calculator is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The calculator at this link http://homer.freeshell.org/dd.cgi is the best in terms of explaining doomsday algorithm cleanly and clearly for human, with one little caveat.

If you input [2/29/1900](http://homer.freeshell.org/dd.cgi?date=2%2F29%2F1900), it would say it's a Thursday. Well, there is no 2/29/1900, because it's not a [leap year](http://exercism.io/exercises/clojure/leap/readme).

Of course if your input 1/35/2016, it would "garbage-in-garbage-out" for you as well.

Imagine there are only 364 days in a year, then the day of week for each date will never change year after year, because `mod(364,7)==0`.

But we have 365 days a year, so the day steps forward 1 each year, that's where the second term `mod(year, 7)` comes from.

In addition, every 4 year, there is a leap year, which contributes to the last term `mod(year, 4)`.

But every 100 years, you subtract a leap year, and every 400 years, you add one leap year. That's where the first term "3,2,0,5" comes in.

You see, it's all because of this leap year, and `mod(365,7)==1` business.

7/11, 5to9 helps to remember table Z greatly.